# How to avoid the -1 in this case

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table `votes`, where `voteType 1 = a negative vote, voteType 0 = a positive vote`.

```
"id"    "votedElm"  "voteType"  "voteProcessed" "country"
"3"     "6"         "1"         "0"             "US"//1-1=0

"4"     "8"         "0"         "0"             "US"//2+0-1=1
"9"     "8"         "1"         "0"             "US"

"5"     "9"         "0"         "0"             "US"//2+0-1=1
"10"    "9"         "1"         "0"             "US"
```

and this my table `likes`

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes"
    6       10      3           US          1
    8       10      7           US          2
    9       10      7           US          2
```

In the above, I run the following sql to count the votes in `votes` and then add or subtract them from the likes.

```
SELECT
  votedElm,
  SUM(CASE WHEN voteType = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS Totalcount 
FROM votes 
WHERE country = 'US'
GROUP BY votedElm;
```

However, for `id 6 in votes`, when using the above query, the result is `-1`. So, `1 (in likes) minus -1 = 2`. The result I wanted was `0`.
Also, for `8 and 9` in the `votes` table, the result should have been `1` `(2-1+0=1)`. Here it show as `0`.

Can you see where I'm going wrong and how I can get this right?

Comment: "voteType 1 = a negative vote, voteType 2 = a positive vote." --- whereas in the table example there are 1s and 0s

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I'm a few steps away from going totally insane.

Comment: " the result is -1. So, 1 (in likes) minus -1 = 2 "  what is this?

Comment: @diEcho 1 from the table likes, minus the -1 got by running the sql from the table votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want to show the votes in negative.So.First count the number of vote than minus the number of unlike..... Try like this...

```
 Select voteby,(Count(votetype)-Sum(Case when votetype=1 then 1 else 0 end)) as b
    from t group by voteby
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f287c/9)

Comment: I got a couple more things you could do (not for free). See my profile for contact info. if you're interested. Thanks for helping with this.

Comment: @Norman your most welcome ...but before contacting i wana  know what kind of help you looking for,,,,

Comment: Most related to MySql and sql. That kind. Creating sql queries, events and the like. Nothing impossible.

Comment: @Norman i can try but i don't guarantee you that i m able tyo slove all my email id is amit521990@yahoo.com